# PieDonut how to change color of pie and donut

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, donut-chart

```
library(ggplot2)
library(moonBook)
library(webr)
PieDonut(mtcars,aes(gear,carb),start=3*pi/2,explode=3,explodeDonut=TRUE,maxx=1.7)
```

I took the example from https://cardiomoon.github.io/webr/reference/PieDonut.html . I want to change the color of pie and donut, but it doesn't work when I assign color = c(...) in the function.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not easily possible as of the moment. As far as I get it the (fill) colors are hard-coded. Via `color` you could only set the border color of the bars or pies or donuts.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code they are hard-coded inside `PieDonut`. The plot returned at the end is actually two ggplots printed on the same page. The final one that's printed is the outer ring e.g. if you try storing the object then printing, you will only see half of the plot:

```
f <- PieDonut(mtcars,aes(gear,carb),start=3*pi/2,explode=3,explodeDonut=TRUE,maxx=1.7)
plot(f)
```

Inside the function the main colours for the inner ring are created with `mainCol <- gg_color_hue(3)` and the outer shades with `makeSubColor(mainCol, no = 4)` in your example.

If you really need it in new colours, you can copy the code from the console, swap out `gg_color_hue` with a different palette function like `RColorBrewer::brewer.pal` e.g. below. I wouldn't recommend using this long term though as the function is apt to change

```
PieDonutCustom <- function (data, mapping, start = getOption("PieDonut.start", 
                                           0), addPieLabel = TRUE, addDonutLabel = TRUE, showRatioDonut = TRUE, 
          showRatioPie = TRUE, ratioByGroup = TRUE, showRatioThreshold = getOption("PieDonut.showRatioThreshold", 
                                                                                   0.02), labelposition = getOption("PieDonut.labelposition", 
                                                                                                                    2), labelpositionThreshold = 0.1, r0 = getOption("PieDonut.r0", 
                                                                                                                                                                     0.3), r1 = getOption("PieDonut.r1", 1), r2 = getOption("PieDonut.r2", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1.2), explode = NULL, selected = NULL, explodePos = 0.1, 
          color = "white", pieAlpha = 0.8, donutAlpha = 1, maxx = NULL, 
          showPieName = TRUE, showDonutName = FALSE, title = NULL, 
          pieLabelSize = 4, donutLabelSize = 3, titlesize = 5, explodePie = TRUE, 
          explodeDonut = FALSE, use.label = TRUE, use.labels = TRUE, 
          family = getOption("PieDonut.family", ""), palette_name="Dark2")
{
  (cols = colnames(data))
  if (use.labels) 
    data = moonBook::addLabelDf(data, mapping)
  count <- NULL
  if ("count" %in% names(mapping)) 
    count <- moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "count")
  count
  pies <- donuts <- NULL
  (pies = moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "pies"))
  if (is.null(pies)) 
    (pies = moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "pie"))
  if (is.null(pies)) 
    (pies = moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "x"))
  (donuts = moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "donuts"))
  if (is.null(donuts)) 
    (donuts = moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "donut"))
  if (is.null(donuts)) 
    (donuts = moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "y"))
  if (!is.null(count)) {
    df <- data %>% group_by(.data[[pies]]) %>% dplyr::summarize(Freq = sum(.data[[count]]))
    df
  }
  else {
    df = data.frame(table(data[[pies]]))
  }
  colnames(df)[1] = pies
  df$end = cumsum(df$Freq)
  df$start = dplyr::lag(df$end)
  df$start[1] = 0
  total = sum(df$Freq)
  df$start1 = df$start * 2 * pi/total
  df$end1 = df$end * 2 * pi/total
  df$start1 = df$start1 + start
  df$end1 = df$end1 + start
  df$focus = 0
  if (explodePie) 
    df$focus[explode] = explodePos
  df$mid = (df$start1 + df$end1)/2
  df$x = ifelse(df$focus == 0, 0, df$focus * sin(df$mid))
  df$y = ifelse(df$focus == 0, 0, df$focus * cos(df$mid))
  df$label = df[[pies]]
  df$ratio = df$Freq/sum(df$Freq)
  if (showRatioPie) {
    df$label = ifelse(df$ratio >= showRatioThreshold, paste0(df$label, 
                                                             "\n(", scales::percent(df$ratio), ")"), 
                      as.character(df$label))
  }
  df$labelx = (r0 + r1)/2 * sin(df$mid) + df$x
  df$labely = (r0 + r1)/2 * cos(df$mid) + df$y
  if (!is.factor(df[[pies]])) 
    df[[pies]] <- factor(df[[pies]])
  df
  mainCol = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(nrow(df), name=palette_name)
  df$radius = r1
  df$radius[df$focus != 0] = df$radius[df$focus != 0] + df$focus[df$focus != 
                                                                   0]
  df$hjust = ifelse((df$mid%%(2 * pi)) > pi, 1, 0)
  df$vjust = ifelse(((df$mid%%(2 * pi)) < (pi/2)) | (df$mid%%(2 * 
                                                                pi) > (pi * 3/2)), 0, 1)
  df$segx = df$radius * sin(df$mid)
  df$segy = df$radius * cos(df$mid)
  df$segxend = (df$radius + 0.05) * sin(df$mid)
  df$segyend = (df$radius + 0.05) * cos(df$mid)
  df
  if (!is.null(donuts)) {
    subColor = makeSubColor(mainCol, no = length(unique(data[[donuts]])))
    subColor
    data
    if (!is.null(count)) {
      df3 <- as.data.frame(data[c(donuts, pies, count)])
      colnames(df3) = c("donut", "pie", "Freq")
      df3
      df3 <- eval(parse(text = "complete(df3,donut,pie)"))
      df3$Freq[is.na(df3$Freq)] = 0
      if (!is.factor(df3[[1]])) 
        df3[[1]] = factor(df3[[1]])
      if (!is.factor(df3[[2]])) 
        df3[[2]] = factor(df3[[2]])
      df3 <- df3 %>% arrange(.data$pie, .data$donut)
      a <- df3 %>% spread(.data$pie, value = .data$Freq)
      a = as.data.frame(a)
      a
      rownames(a) = a[[1]]
      a = a[-1]
      a
      colnames(df3)[1:2] = c(donuts, pies)
    }
    else {
      df3 = data.frame(table(data[[donuts]], data[[pies]]), 
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      colnames(df3)[1:2] = c(donuts, pies)
      a = table(data[[donuts]], data[[pies]])
      a
    }
    a
    df3
    df3$group = rep(colSums(a), each = nrow(a))
    df3$pie = rep(1:ncol(a), each = nrow(a))
    total = sum(df3$Freq)
    total
    df3$ratio1 = df3$Freq/total
    df3
    if (ratioByGroup) {
      df3$ratio = scales::percent(df3$Freq/df3$group)
    }
    else {
      df3$ratio <- scales::percent(df3$ratio1)
    }
    df3$end = cumsum(df3$Freq)
    df3
    df3$start = dplyr::lag(df3$end)
    df3$start[1] = 0
    df3$start1 = df3$start * 2 * pi/total
    df3$end1 = df3$end * 2 * pi/total
    df3$start1 = df3$start1 + start
    df3$end1 = df3$end1 + start
    df3$mid = (df3$start1 + df3$end1)/2
    df3$focus = 0
    if (!is.null(selected)) {
      df3$focus[selected] = explodePos
    }
    else if (!is.null(explode)) {
      selected = c()
      for (i in 1:length(explode)) {
        start = 1 + nrow(a) * (explode[i] - 1)
        selected = c(selected, start:(start + nrow(a) - 
                                        1))
      }
      selected
      df3$focus[selected] = explodePos
    }
    df3
    df3$x = 0
    df3$y = 0
    df
    if (!is.null(explode)) {
      explode
      for (i in 1:length(explode)) {
        xpos = df$focus[explode[i]] * sin(df$mid[explode[i]])
        ypos = df$focus[explode[i]] * cos(df$mid[explode[i]])
        df3$x[df3$pie == explode[i]] = xpos
        df3$y[df3$pie == explode[i]] = ypos
      }
    }
    df3$no = 1:nrow(df3)
    df3$label = df3[[donuts]]
    if (showRatioDonut) {
      if (max(nchar(levels(df3$label))) <= 2) 
        df3$label = paste0(df3$label, "(", df3$ratio, 
                           ")")
      else df3$label = paste0(df3$label, "\n(", df3$ratio, 
                              ")")
    }
    df3$label[df3$ratio1 == 0] = ""
    df3$label[df3$ratio1 < showRatioThreshold] = ""
    df3$hjust = ifelse((df3$mid%%(2 * pi)) > pi, 1, 0)
    df3$vjust = ifelse(((df3$mid%%(2 * pi)) < (pi/2)) | (df3$mid%%(2 * 
                                                                     pi) > (pi * 3/2)), 0, 1)
    df3$no = factor(df3$no)
    df3
    labelposition
    if (labelposition > 0) {
      df3$radius = r2
      if (explodeDonut) 
        df3$radius[df3$focus != 0] = df3$radius[df3$focus != 
                                                  0] + df3$focus[df3$focus != 0]
      df3$segx = df3$radius * sin(df3$mid) + df3$x
      df3$segy = df3$radius * cos(df3$mid) + df3$y
      df3$segxend = (df3$radius + 0.05) * sin(df3$mid) + 
        df3$x
      df3$segyend = (df3$radius + 0.05) * cos(df3$mid) + 
        df3$y
      if (labelposition == 2) 
        df3$radius = (r1 + r2)/2
      df3$labelx = (df3$radius) * sin(df3$mid) + df3$x
      df3$labely = (df3$radius) * cos(df3$mid) + df3$y
    }
    else {
      df3$radius = (r1 + r2)/2
      if (explodeDonut) 
        df3$radius[df3$focus != 0] = df3$radius[df3$focus != 
                                                  0] + df3$focus[df3$focus != 0]
      df3$labelx = df3$radius * sin(df3$mid) + df3$x
      df3$labely = df3$radius * cos(df3$mid) + df3$y
    }
    df3$segx[df3$ratio1 == 0] = 0
    df3$segxend[df3$ratio1 == 0] = 0
    df3$segy[df3$ratio1 == 0] = 0
    df3$segyend[df3$ratio1 == 0] = 0
    if (labelposition == 0) {
      df3$segx[df3$ratio1 < showRatioThreshold] = 0
      df3$segxend[df3$ratio1 < showRatioThreshold] = 0
      df3$segy[df3$ratio1 < showRatioThreshold] = 0
      df3$segyend[df3$ratio1 < showRatioThreshold] = 0
    }
    df3
    del = which(df3$Freq == 0)
    del
    if (length(del) > 0) 
      subColor <- subColor[-del]
    subColor
  }
  p <- ggplot() + ggforce::theme_no_axes() + coord_fixed()
  if (is.null(maxx)) {
    r3 = r2 + 0.3
  }
  else {
    r3 = maxx
  }
  p1 <- p + ggforce::geom_arc_bar(aes_string(x0 = "x", y0 = "y", 
                                    r0 = as.character(r0), r = as.character(r1), start = "start1", 
                                    end = "end1", fill = pies), alpha = pieAlpha, color = color, 
                         data = df) + transparent() + scale_fill_manual(values = mainCol) + 
    xlim(r3 * c(-1, 1)) + ylim(r3 * c(-1, 1)) + guides(fill = FALSE)
  if ((labelposition == 1) & (is.null(donuts))) {
    p1 <- p1 + geom_segment(aes_string(x = "segx", 
                                       y = "segy", xend = "segxend", yend = "segyend"), 
                            data = df) + geom_text(aes_string(x = "segxend", 
                                                              y = "segyend", label = "label", hjust = "hjust", 
                                                              vjust = "vjust"), size = pieLabelSize, data = df, 
                                                   family = family)
  }
  else if ((labelposition == 2) & (is.null(donuts))) {
    p1 <- p1 + geom_segment(aes_string(x = "segx", 
                                       y = "segy", xend = "segxend", yend = "segyend"), 
                            data = df[df$ratio < labelpositionThreshold, ]) + 
      geom_text(aes_string(x = "segxend", y = "segyend", 
                           label = "label", hjust = "hjust", 
                           vjust = "vjust"), size = pieLabelSize, 
                data = df[df$ratio < labelpositionThreshold, 
                ], family = family) + geom_text(aes_string(x = "labelx", 
                                                           y = "labely", label = "label"), size = pieLabelSize, 
                                                data = df[df$ratio >= labelpositionThreshold, ], 
                                                family = family)
  }
  else {
    p1 <- p1 + geom_text(aes_string(x = "labelx", y = "labely", 
                                    label = "label"), size = pieLabelSize, data = df, 
                         family = family)
  }
  if (showPieName) 
    p1 <- p1 + annotate("text", x = 0, y = 0, label = pies, 
                        size = titlesize, family = family)
  p1 <- p1 + theme(text = element_text(family = family))
  if (!is.null(donuts)) {
    if (explodeDonut) {
      p3 <- p + ggforce::geom_arc_bar(aes_string(x0 = "x", 
                                        y0 = "y", r0 = as.character(r1), r = as.character(r2), 
                                        start = "start1", end = "end1", fill = "no", 
                                        explode = "focus"), alpha = donutAlpha, 
                             color = color, data = df3)
    }
    else {
      p3 <- p + ggforce::geom_arc_bar(aes_string(x0 = "x", 
                                        y0 = "y", r0 = as.character(r1), r = as.character(r2), 
                                        start = "start1", end = "end1", fill = "no"), 
                             alpha = donutAlpha, color = color, data = df3)
    }
    p3 <- p3 + transparent() + scale_fill_manual(values = subColor) + 
      xlim(r3 * c(-1, 1)) + ylim(r3 * c(-1, 1)) + guides(fill = FALSE)
    p3
    if (labelposition == 1) {
      p3 <- p3 + geom_segment(aes_string(x = "segx", 
                                         y = "segy", xend = "segxend", yend = "segyend"), 
                              data = df3) + geom_text(aes_string(x = "segxend", 
                                                                 y = "segyend", label = "label", hjust = "hjust", 
                                                                 vjust = "vjust"), size = donutLabelSize, 
                                                      data = df3, family = family)
    }
    else if (labelposition == 0) {
      p3 <- p3 + geom_text(aes_string(x = "labelx", 
                                      y = "labely", label = "label"), size = donutLabelSize, 
                           data = df3, family = family)
    }
    else {
      p3 <- p3 + geom_segment(aes_string(x = "segx", 
                                         y = "segy", xend = "segxend", yend = "segyend"), 
                              data = df3[df3$ratio1 < labelpositionThreshold, 
                              ]) + geom_text(aes_string(x = "segxend", 
                                                        y = "segyend", label = "label", hjust = "hjust", 
                                                        vjust = "vjust"), size = donutLabelSize, 
                                             data = df3[df3$ratio1 < labelpositionThreshold, 
                                             ], family = family) + geom_text(aes_string(x = "labelx", 
                                                                                        y = "labely", label = "label"), size = donutLabelSize, 
                                                                             data = df3[df3$ratio1 >= labelpositionThreshold, 
                                                                             ], family = family)
    }
    if (!is.null(title)) 
      p3 <- p3 + annotate("text", x = 0, y = r3, 
                          label = title, size = titlesize, family = family)
    else if (showDonutName) 
      p3 <- p3 + annotate("text", x = (-1) * r3, 
                          y = r3, label = donuts, hjust = 0, size = titlesize, 
                          family = family)
    p3 <- p3 + theme(text = element_text(family = family))
    grid::grid.newpage()
    print(p1, vp = grid::viewport(height = 1, width = 1))
    print(p3, vp = grid::viewport(height = 1, width = 1))
  }
  else {
    p1
  }
}
```

```
library(ggplot2)
library(moonBook)
library(webr)
library(RColorBrewer)
PieDonutCustom(mtcars,aes(gear,carb),start=3*pi/2,explode=3,explodeDonut=TRUE,maxx=1.7,
               palette_name = "Dark2")
PieDonutCustom(mtcars,aes(gear,carb),start=3*pi/2,explode=3,explodeDonut=TRUE,maxx=1.7,
               palette_name = "Set1")
```

[image]

If you want to use a different palette/library, search for `mainCol = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(nrow(df), name=palette_name)` in the code, and replace the function here with yours

Answer (score 1):

Jonny, thank you so much for that code, it works great to tweak the colours (which also did not follow the same order of categories, when category number changed). I was frustrated by the inability to save the full pie_donut, mainly because I wanted to make a composite graph of three of them. So I took your above function - to get the ability to play with the colour scheme - and replaced the printing lines that were in the original function at the end with some {patchwork}, to allow print the graph as one object only, and therefore saving. In the below, I purposely left the replaced lines, commented out, to highlight where the change has been made.

```
pie_donut_full <-
  function (data,
            mapping,
            start = getOption("PieDonut.start",
                              0),
            addPieLabel = TRUE,
            addDonutLabel = TRUE,
            showRatioDonut = TRUE,
            showRatioPie = TRUE,
            ratioByGroup = TRUE,
            showRatioThreshold = getOption("PieDonut.showRatioThreshold",
                                           0.02),
            labelposition = getOption("PieDonut.labelposition",
                                      2),
            labelpositionThreshold = 0.1,
            r0 = getOption("PieDonut.r0",
                           0.3),
            r1 = getOption("PieDonut.r1", 1),
            r2 = getOption("PieDonut.r2",
                           1.2),
            explode = NULL,
            selected = NULL,
            explodePos = 0.1,
            color = "white",
            pieAlpha = 0.8,
            donutAlpha = 1,
            maxx = NULL,
            showPieName = TRUE,
            showDonutName = FALSE,
            title = NULL,
            pieLabelSize = 4,
            donutLabelSize = 3,
            titlesize = 5,
            explodePie = TRUE,
            explodeDonut = FALSE,
            use.label = TRUE,
            use.labels = TRUE,
            family = getOption("PieDonut.family", ""),
            palette_name = "Dark2")
  {
    (cols = colnames(data))
    if (use.labels)
      data = moonBook::addLabelDf(data, mapping)
    count <- NULL
    if ("count" %in% names(mapping))
      count <- moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "count")
    count
    pies <- donuts <- NULL
    (pies = moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "pies"))
    if (is.null(pies))
      (pies = moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "pie"))
    if (is.null(pies))
      (pies = moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "x"))
    (donuts = moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "donuts"))
    if (is.null(donuts))
      (donuts = moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "donut"))
    if (is.null(donuts))
      (donuts = moonBook::getMapping(mapping, "y"))
    if (!is.null(count)) {
      df <-
        data %>% group_by(.data[[pies]]) %>% dplyr::summarize(Freq = sum(.data[[count]]))
      df
    }
    else {
      df = data.frame(table(data[[pies]]))
    }
    colnames(df)[1] = pies
    df$end = cumsum(df$Freq)
    df$start = dplyr::lag(df$end)
    df$start[1] = 0
    total = sum(df$Freq)
    df$start1 = df$start * 2 * pi / total
    df$end1 = df$end * 2 * pi / total
    df$start1 = df$start1 + start
    df$end1 = df$end1 + start
    df$focus = 0
    if (explodePie)
      df$focus[explode] = explodePos
    df$mid = (df$start1 + df$end1) / 2
    df$x = ifelse(df$focus == 0, 0, df$focus * sin(df$mid))
    df$y = ifelse(df$focus == 0, 0, df$focus * cos(df$mid))
    df$label = df[[pies]]
    df$ratio = df$Freq / sum(df$Freq)
    if (showRatioPie) {
      df$label = ifelse(
        df$ratio >= showRatioThreshold,
        paste0(df$label,
               "\n(", scales::percent(df$ratio), ")"),
        as.character(df$label)
      )
    }
    df$labelx = (r0 + r1) / 2 * sin(df$mid) + df$x
    df$labely = (r0 + r1) / 2 * cos(df$mid) + df$y
    if (!is.factor(df[[pies]]))
      df[[pies]] <- factor(df[[pies]])
    df
    mainCol = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(nrow(df), name = palette_name)
    df$radius = r1
    df$radius[df$focus != 0] = df$radius[df$focus != 0] + df$focus[df$focus !=
                                                                     0]
    df$hjust = ifelse((df$mid %% (2 * pi)) > pi, 1, 0)
    df$vjust = ifelse(((df$mid %% (2 * pi)) < (pi / 2)) |
                        (df$mid %% (2 *
                                      pi) > (pi * 3 /
                                               2)), 0, 1)
    df$segx = df$radius * sin(df$mid)
    df$segy = df$radius * cos(df$mid)
    df$segxend = (df$radius + 0.05) * sin(df$mid)
    df$segyend = (df$radius + 0.05) * cos(df$mid)
    df
    if (!is.null(donuts)) {
      subColor = makeSubColor(mainCol, no = length(unique(data[[donuts]])))
      subColor
      data
      if (!is.null(count)) {
        df3 <- as.data.frame(data[c(donuts, pies, count)])
        colnames(df3) = c("donut", "pie", "Freq")
        df3
        df3 <- eval(parse(text = "complete(df3,donut,pie)"))
        df3$Freq[is.na(df3$Freq)] = 0
        if (!is.factor(df3[[1]]))
          df3[[1]] = factor(df3[[1]])
        if (!is.factor(df3[[2]]))
          df3[[2]] = factor(df3[[2]])
        df3 <- df3 %>% arrange(.data$pie, .data$donut)
        a <- df3 %>% spread(.data$pie, value = .data$Freq)
        a = as.data.frame(a)
        a
        rownames(a) = a[[1]]
        a = a[-1]
        a
        colnames(df3)[1:2] = c(donuts, pies)
      }
      else {
        df3 = data.frame(table(data[[donuts]], data[[pies]]),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        colnames(df3)[1:2] = c(donuts, pies)
        a = table(data[[donuts]], data[[pies]])
        a
      }
      a
      df3
      df3$group = rep(colSums(a), each = nrow(a))
      df3$pie = rep(1:ncol(a), each = nrow(a))
      total = sum(df3$Freq)
      total
      df3$ratio1 = df3$Freq / total
      df3
      if (ratioByGroup) {
        df3$ratio = scales::percent(df3$Freq / df3$group)
      }
      else {
        df3$ratio <- scales::percent(df3$ratio1)
      }
      df3$end = cumsum(df3$Freq)
      df3
      df3$start = dplyr::lag(df3$end)
      df3$start[1] = 0
      df3$start1 = df3$start * 2 * pi / total
      df3$end1 = df3$end * 2 * pi / total
      df3$start1 = df3$start1 + start
      df3$end1 = df3$end1 + start
      df3$mid = (df3$start1 + df3$end1) / 2
      df3$focus = 0
      if (!is.null(selected)) {
        df3$focus[selected] = explodePos
      }
      else if (!is.null(explode)) {
        selected = c()
        for (i in 1:length(explode)) {
          start = 1 + nrow(a) * (explode[i] - 1)
          selected = c(selected, start:(start + nrow(a) -
                                          1))
        }
        selected
        df3$focus[selected] = explodePos
      }
      df3
      df3$x = 0
      df3$y = 0
      df
      if (!is.null(explode)) {
        explode
        for (i in 1:length(explode)) {
          xpos = df$focus[explode[i]] * sin(df$mid[explode[i]])
          ypos = df$focus[explode[i]] * cos(df$mid[explode[i]])
          df3$x[df3$pie == explode[i]] = xpos
          df3$y[df3$pie == explode[i]] = ypos
        }
      }
      df3$no = 1:nrow(df3)
      df3$label = df3[[donuts]]
      if (showRatioDonut) {
        if (max(nchar(levels(df3$label))) <= 2)
          df3$label = paste0(df3$label, "(", df3$ratio,
                             ")")
        else
          df3$label = paste0(df3$label, "\n(", df3$ratio,
                             ")")
      }
      df3$label[df3$ratio1 == 0] = ""
      df3$label[df3$ratio1 < showRatioThreshold] = ""
      df3$hjust = ifelse((df3$mid %% (2 * pi)) > pi, 1, 0)
      df3$vjust = ifelse(((df3$mid %% (2 * pi)) < (pi / 2)) |
                           (df3$mid %% (2 *
                                          pi) > (pi * 3 /
                                                   2)), 0, 1)
      df3$no = factor(df3$no)
      df3
      labelposition
      if (labelposition > 0) {
        df3$radius = r2
        if (explodeDonut)
          df3$radius[df3$focus != 0] = df3$radius[df3$focus !=
                                                    0] + df3$focus[df3$focus != 0]
        df3$segx = df3$radius * sin(df3$mid) + df3$x
        df3$segy = df3$radius * cos(df3$mid) + df3$y
        df3$segxend = (df3$radius + 0.05) * sin(df3$mid) +
          df3$x
        df3$segyend = (df3$radius + 0.05) * cos(df3$mid) +
          df3$y
        if (labelposition == 2)
          df3$radius = (r1 + r2) / 2
        df3$labelx = (df3$radius) * sin(df3$mid) + df3$x
        df3$labely = (df3$radius) * cos(df3$mid) + df3$y
      }
      else {
        df3$radius = (r1 + r2) / 2
        if (explodeDonut)
          df3$radius[df3$focus != 0] = df3$radius[df3$focus !=
                                                    0] + df3$focus[df3$focus != 0]
        df3$labelx = df3$radius * sin(df3$mid) + df3$x
        df3$labely = df3$radius * cos(df3$mid) + df3$y
      }
      df3$segx[df3$ratio1 == 0] = 0
      df3$segxend[df3$ratio1 == 0] = 0
      df3$segy[df3$ratio1 == 0] = 0
      df3$segyend[df3$ratio1 == 0] = 0
      if (labelposition == 0) {
        df3$segx[df3$ratio1 < showRatioThreshold] = 0
        df3$segxend[df3$ratio1 < showRatioThreshold] = 0
        df3$segy[df3$ratio1 < showRatioThreshold] = 0
        df3$segyend[df3$ratio1 < showRatioThreshold] = 0
      }
      df3
      del = which(df3$Freq == 0)
      del
      if (length(del) > 0)
        subColor <- subColor[-del]
      subColor
    }
    p <- ggplot() + ggforce::theme_no_axes() + coord_fixed()
    if (is.null(maxx)) {
      r3 = r2 + 0.3
    }
    else {
      r3 = maxx
    }
    p1 <- p + ggforce::geom_arc_bar(
      aes_string(
        x0 = "x",
        y0 = "y",
        r0 = as.character(r0),
        r = as.character(r1),
        start = "start1",
        end = "end1",
        fill = pies
      ),
      alpha = pieAlpha,
      color = color,
      data = df
    ) + transparent() + scale_fill_manual(values = mainCol) +
      xlim(r3 * c(-1, 1)) + ylim(r3 * c(-1, 1)) + guides(fill = FALSE)
    if ((labelposition == 1) & (is.null(donuts))) {
      p1 <- p1 + geom_segment(aes_string(
        x = "segx",
        y = "segy",
        xend = "segxend",
        yend = "segyend"
      ),
      data = df) + geom_text(
        aes_string(
          x = "segxend",
          y = "segyend",
          label = "label",
          hjust = "hjust",
          vjust = "vjust"
        ),
        size = pieLabelSize,
        data = df,
        family = family
      )
    }
    else if ((labelposition == 2) & (is.null(donuts))) {
      p1 <- p1 + geom_segment(aes_string(
        x = "segx",
        y = "segy",
        xend = "segxend",
        yend = "segyend"
      ),
      data = df[df$ratio < labelpositionThreshold,]) +
        geom_text(
          aes_string(
            x = "segxend",
            y = "segyend",
            label = "label",
            hjust = "hjust",
            vjust = "vjust"
          ),
          size = pieLabelSize,
          data = df[df$ratio < labelpositionThreshold,],
          family = family
        ) + geom_text(
          aes_string(x = "labelx",
                     y = "labely", label = "label"),
          size = pieLabelSize,
          data = df[df$ratio >= labelpositionThreshold,],
          family = family
        )
    }
    else {
      p1 <- p1 + geom_text(
        aes_string(x = "labelx", y = "labely",
                   label = "label"),
        size = pieLabelSize,
        data = df,
        family = family
      )
    }
    if (showPieName)
      p1 <- p1 + annotate(
        "text",
        x = 0,
        y = 0,
        label = pies,
        size = titlesize,
        family = family
      )
    p1 <- p1 + theme(text = element_text(family = family))
    if (!is.null(donuts)) {
      if (explodeDonut) {
        p3 <- p + ggforce::geom_arc_bar(
          aes_string(
            x0 = "x",
            y0 = "y",
            r0 = as.character(r1),
            r = as.character(r2),
            start = "start1",
            end = "end1",
            fill = "no",
            explode = "focus"
          ),
          alpha = donutAlpha,
          color = color,
          data = df3
        )
      }
      else {
        p3 <- p + ggforce::geom_arc_bar(
          aes_string(
            x0 = "x",
            y0 = "y",
            r0 = as.character(r1),
            r = as.character(r2),
            start = "start1",
            end = "end1",
            fill = "no"
          ),
          alpha = donutAlpha,
          color = color,
          data = df3
        )
      }
      p3 <-
        p3 + transparent() + scale_fill_manual(values = subColor) +
        xlim(r3 * c(-1, 1)) + ylim(r3 * c(-1, 1)) + guides(fill = FALSE)
      p3
      if (labelposition == 1) {
        p3 <- p3 + geom_segment(aes_string(
          x = "segx",
          y = "segy",
          xend = "segxend",
          yend = "segyend"
        ),
        data = df3) + geom_text(
          aes_string(
            x = "segxend",
            y = "segyend",
            label = "label",
            hjust = "hjust",
            vjust = "vjust"
          ),
          size = donutLabelSize,
          data = df3,
          family = family
        )
      }
      else if (labelposition == 0) {
        p3 <- p3 + geom_text(
          aes_string(x = "labelx",
                     y = "labely", label = "label"),
          size = donutLabelSize,
          data = df3,
          family = family
        )
      }
      else {
        p3 <- p3 + geom_segment(aes_string(
          x = "segx",
          y = "segy",
          xend = "segxend",
          yend = "segyend"
        ),
        data = df3[df3$ratio1 < labelpositionThreshold,]) + geom_text(
          aes_string(
            x = "segxend",
            y = "segyend",
            label = "label",
            hjust = "hjust",
            vjust = "vjust"
          ),
          size = donutLabelSize,
          data = df3[df3$ratio1 < labelpositionThreshold,],
          family = family
        ) + geom_text(
          aes_string(x = "labelx",
                     y = "labely", label = "label"),
          size = donutLabelSize,
          data = df3[df3$ratio1 >= labelpositionThreshold,],
          family = family
        )
      }
      if (!is.null(title))
        p3 <- p3 + annotate(
          "text",
          x = 0,
          y = r3,
          label = title,
          size = titlesize,
          family = family
        )
      else if (showDonutName)
        p3 <- p3 + annotate(
          "text",
          x = (-1) * r3,
          y = r3,
          label = donuts,
          hjust = 0,
          size = titlesize,
          family = family
        )
      p3 <- p3 + theme(text = element_text(family = family))
      full_pd <- p1 + patchwork::inset_element(
        p3, left = 0, right = 1, bottom = 0, top = 1)
      print(full_pd)
      # grid::grid.newpage()
      # print(p1, vp = grid::viewport(height = 1, width = 1))
      # print(p3, vp = grid::viewport(height = 1, width = 1))
    }
    else {
      p1
    }
  }
```

Comment: This answers a different question than was asked.