# Piedonut chart's label text position adjustment and pie and donut's color modification

Tags: pie-chart, donut-chart

I have the following data frame.

```
inward_2022_region_income <- data.frame(
  Region = c("South Asia", "Europe & Central Asia", "Latin America & Caribbean", "East Asia & Pacific", "Middle East & North Africa", "East Asia & Pacific", "Europe & Central Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Europe & Central Asia", "Latin America & Caribbean"),
  Income_Group = c("Lower middle income", "High income", "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", "Lower middle income", "Lower middle income", "Lower middle income", "Lower middle income", "Upper middle income", "Lower middle income"),
  remittance_received = c(164363767273, 136183611220, 117465697000, 62839165858, 58043307652, 42473756742, 38171200000, 37431728299, 33900928280, 24964975447)
)
```

I've created a piedonut chart with the following codes.

```
PieDonut(inward_2022_region_income,
         aes(pies = Country_Income,
             donuts = Region,
             count = remittance_received),
         explode = 1, 
         explodeDonut = TRUE,
         ratioByGroup = FALSE,
         addDonutLabel = FALSE,
         labelposition = 0.5,
         donutLabelSize = 2,
         pieLabelSize = 2,
         titlesize = 4,
         use.labels = FALSE,
         title = "Inward Remittances by Income Group and Region",
         maxx = 1.9,
         r0 = 0,
         r1 = 0.8,
         r2 = 1.2, 
         start = pi/1,
         showPieName = FALSE, 
         showRatioThreshold = FALSE)
```

The piedonut chart has been plotted as follows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7kTs.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OS7I.png)

The following 3 items are what I am struggling with.

[Problem 1]
I would like to make the donut parts of 'High income' Pie unoverlapped and seen properly.

[Problem 2]
I would like to the percentage values shown in labels as rounded numbers.

[Problem 3]
I would like to change the colors of pie and donuts by using the following color codes.
Colors: c("#0197FF", "#5938E4", "#22B2A4", "#15A800", "#B0DB02", "#E8B321", "#DB5614", "#F66DBD")

Answer (score 0):

I have a same Problem 2 with you. Yesterday, I tried this way and it fixed. I created another column which calculate % contribution, for example **remittance_received** in your case using `mutate(remittance_received1=remittance_received/sum(remittance_received)*100) dat$remittance_received <- round(dat$remittance_received,0)`.
In the `count()` function within **aes()**, then using `count=remittance_received1`.
Hope this works for you.

Comment: Looking forward to see any suggestion for your **Problem 1**

Comment: Also, I have an issue with exporting or save the chart. When ever I call the figure, the donuts part is missing. Do you experience this issue? and know how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I could manage to modify parts of the original **PieDonut** function for all the problems:

For Problem 1: What kind of worked for me was to replace the *geom_text()* with *ggrepel::geom_text_repel*

For Problem 2: I modified the section of the original function where labels were created, like this:

replaced this section:

```
       paste0(df$label,
               "\n(", scales::percent(df$ratio), ")"),
        as.character(df$label)
```

with:

```
       paste0(df$label,
               "\n(", scales::label_percent(accuracy = 1)(df$ratio), ")"),
        as.character(df$label)
```

For Problem  3: please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68095243/piedonut-how-to-change-color-of-pie-and-donut).

I hope this helps.